# bundler exec "LoadError: cannot load such file"

Tags: ruby, exec, bundle, project

Source code of the project for anyone interested: https://github.com/clockworkpc/verbalyser

Ruby version: ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]

From the root directory of this project ("verbalyser") I am trying to run the simple command:

```
bundle exec exe/verbalyser
```

But I keep on getting this error message:

```
bundler: failed to load command: exe/verbalyser (exe/verbalyser)
LoadError: cannot load such file -- verbalyser
  exe/verbalyser:2:in `require'
  exe/verbalyser:2:in `<top (required)>'
```

Here are the contents of the file verbalyser/exe/verbalyser, which has been made executable (chmod +x):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "verbalyser"
```

Here are the contents of the Ruby file that this executable is trying to load:

```
require "verbalyser/version"
require "verbalyser/conjugation_scraper"
require "verbalyser/cooljugator_scraper"
require "verbalyser/endings_grouper"
require "verbalyser/lemma_matcher"
require "verbalyser/verb_shortlister"
```

Here is my directory structure:

[image: Directory Structure of Project]

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this. I found the answer to my specific problem somewhere on stack overflow but I can't find the link so I'll repeat what I remember of it.

Basically, the file was recently created and did not exist in bundler's own internal git repository, so I had to add it, and once I did that it worked. I didn't even have to commit the file - just stage it.